# How to save object updates to database with EntityFramework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have the following scenario:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int empId, int deptId, int level)
{
  Employee emp = GetEmployee(empId);
  emp.DeptId = deptId;
  emp.Level = level;

  using (var mye = new MyEntity())
  {
    //this is having no effect?
    wc.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to save the Employee object update back to the database.  The employee does exist in the database.  What should go in the using block?

Comment: how is your `GetEmployee` method work ? are you sure it returns the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach it before modifying, modify, then save changes.

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int empId, int deptId, int level)
{
  Employee emp = GetEmployee(empId);

  using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
  {
   dbContext.Employees.Attach(emp);
   emp.DeptId = deptId;
   emp.Level = level;
   //this is having no effect?
   dbContext.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

You could also attach it, and then set the state to Modified:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int empId, int deptId, int level)
{
  Employee emp = GetEmployee(empId);
  emp.DeptId = deptId;
  emp.Level = level;    

  using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
  {
   dbContext.Employees.Attach(emp);
   dbContext.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
   dbContext.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

And if you only want to send those fields in the update instead of all columns:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int empId, int deptId, int level)
{
  Employee emp = GetEmployee(empId);
  emp.DeptId = deptId;
  emp.Level = level;    

  using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
  {
   dbContext.Employees.Attach(emp);
   dbContext.Entry(emp).Property(p => p.DeptId).IsModified = true;
   dbContext.Entry(emp).Property(p => p.Level).IsModified = true;
   dbContext.SaveChanges()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that.  What would be the difference with the disconnected scenario here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx?

Comment: Yes. Basically, you have to let the object state manager that the entity is modified after attaching.

Comment: Your first example doesn't set the state.  If you assign properties to the object inside the entity using block, state doesn't need to be set?

Comment: It is set by the dbContext if the changes are performed after it is attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your ObjectContext

Comment: I am calling SaveChanges().  It doesn't do anything.  I've updated the OP.

Comment: You need to add the entity to the dbContext before calling SaveChanges.

Comment: Doesn't that attempt to insert a new record?

Comment: Sorry, misread you question, thought it said the object doesn't exist.